# jQuery - Output form data into table

Tags: jquery, forms, input, output

Using jQuery, how can I output (and append) values that were submitted in a form?

For example I input a name and it sould appen as a new table row that contains the name that was in the form.

```
<form>
Name:<input type="text" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>
// Here the name should be appended...within a <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var newName = $('form').find('input[type="text"]').val();
  $('table').append('<tr><td>' + newName + '</td></tr>')
});
```

Comment: is there a way I can click on the row and the text (name) will appear in the form again, so I can edit it?

Maybe something like this?

$('td',row).click(function() {
         $(this).replaceWith("<td>" + newName + "</td>");
    });